# How can subscribers be informed that an already published item has changed?

Tags: rss

I want to implement a very basic RSS feed for a website that has an FAQ.

Subscribers will be informed about new questions/answers. That's great.

But questions will have essential changes in content from time to time (e.g. when a better answer for a question is found). Is RSS able to inform subscribers that such an answer has changed?

If not, what could be a good workaround? I'm thinking of offering another RSS feed which only announces changes to existing questions. Is this "the right way to go"?

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends on what kind of client you want to implement your feed for.

If you are talking about simple RSS readers, there is no real standard to update only one entry that have changed, but most of them are doing long polling, effectively getting all the feed again with the update.

But there are protocols called light and fat pinging that are specifically designed to handle what you want to do, the difference between the two are:

- Light pinging means that the url of the feed that changed will be sent to the subscriber
- Fat pinging means that the updated content of the feed that changed will be sent to the subscriber

One pretty popular protocol (fat-ping) and backed by Google is called [PubSubHubbub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PubSubHubbub). There is a few services using it already, like Blogger, Youtube, MySpace, Tumblr or Wordpress. They have open-source clients for a lot of languages available on [their Github](https://github.com/pubsubhubbub), I recommend taking a look at [their wiki](https://github.com/pubsubhubbub/PubSubHubbub/wiki) if you are interested, which is pretty complete and informative.

Using a second feed for updates do not seems like a good idea, since that's not what it's designed for and would mean that you have to implement a client for the people to install to effectively get the updates.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something with edit or update dates, titles and other XML node values compair old versions with the new versions if a node has been changed to another value, for example:

If you have a variable for your sml nodes that can be changed to an other value you'll be able to check for a change with if statements, for this example I'll check the value of `$title`..

```
<?php
$title = 'My awesome title';
/** Here your php code to get the content and assign variable to all nodes **/
$title_old = $title; /** Get the info your xml script or cached XML data **/
$title_new = 'My awesome title'; /** Use YOUR new value! - requestt the content again after someone clicked the save button or use a crontab to get info on changes every x minutes, hours or days **/
if($title_new == $title_old){
   $title_changed = 'No changes detected to the title node';
    echo $title_changed . ': The title is &quot;' . $title . '&quot;';
  }else{
   $title_changed = 'The title node has been changed';
     echo $title_changed . ': The new title is &quot;' . $title . '&quot;';
}
?>
```

I hope this will bring you into the right direction..

Answer (score 0):

You could format the links in such a way that they include a hash or and ID of the last answer. This way the links will get picked up as fresh, and if you have a custom feed reader it can trace if the link is new or was read by the user

Comment: Could you please give an example for how the feed would look like? At the time being it has the following elements:    
 `<id>tag:adg.access4all.ch,2005:PageDecorator/1</id>`, `<published>2017-02-14T22:51:21+01:00</published>`, `<updated>2017-03-22T15:05:52+01:00</updated>`, `<link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="http://adg.access4all.ch/en/pages/1"/>`. Where would you place the ID?